# Java Converting Data Types

Tags: java, type-conversion

What is the difference of "String.ValueOf(i)" and "Integer.toString(i)"?
What is the best practice for conveting?

"The valueOf() is the static method of String class" what does this mean?

Answer (score 1):

There is no practical difference. When you look at the source code of `String.valudOf(int i)`, it internally calls `Integer.toString(i)`.